# What was the availability of silk in the Waste among the Aiel?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Shadow Rising*, Mat notes that

> Laces and velvets vanished as soon as they were brought out, for astonishing quantities of silver and gold, and ribbons for not much less, but the finest silks just lay there. Silk was cheaper in trade to the east, he overheard a Shaido tell Kadere.

We also learn that an extensive trade route with silk runs through, or did run through the Waste, between Shara and Cairhien, and that the Aiel themselves trade extensively with the Sharans.

However, Aviendha in *A Crown of Swords*:

> —and here she wore a silk dress—of which she now owned four!—and silk stockings instead of stout wool, and a silk shift that made her aware of her skin in a way she never had been before. She could not deny the beauty of the dress, no matter how odd it was to find herself wearing such things, but silk was precious, and rare. A woman might have a scarf of silk, to be worn on feastdays and envied by others. Few women had two. It was different among these wetlanders, though.

What is the actual availability of silk in the Waste?

Comment: This is more a comment you would expect the country girl Egwene to say, since silk was rare and expensive in most parts of the wetlands. >.<

Comment: Aveinhdas comment about silk dresses is more to address the fact that they were not exactly functional as most things that the Aiel did and wore were designed primarily for their function and survival in harsh environments. Though saying this, she does seem to get a little attached to them as time goes on...

Comment: @Theyna  the precious and rare are the key points of her speach i think.

Comment: @Thenya I agree; silk is probably common in the Waste for selling and trading, but not for wearing

Comment: What's the contradiction? Just because they can get it more cheaply from Shara than from the west, doesn't mean it's cheap or easy to get *anywhere*.

Comment: shes saying how plentiful it is, thousands of miles away from its source, and how rare and precious it is, literally feet from the source. while mats statement shows how the aiel dont care about silk, its cheep, and plentiful, while lace and velvet is not.